# change position of TabBar Ionic2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

Is there way to change position of tabBar in my Ionic2 project ?
 Here is my Tabbar html code :

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement='top'>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="selected" tabTitle="Pref1"> </ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="selected" tabTitle="Pref2"> </ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" [rootParams]="selected" tabTitle="Pref3"> </ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" [rootParams]="selected" tabTitle="Pref4"> </ion-tab>
<ion-header>
    <ion-label class="timebar" text-center color="primary">
        Synch {{date|date:'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss'}}
    </ion-label>
</ion-header>
```

```
</iontabs>
```

I can change its position using the `element.style{top:Ypx}` Y is a number 
but that variable can only be found using browsers (F12 shortcut) so writing that in the sass file doesn't work.
I want to mention that this is all the code for the tab Page I don't have an ion-content in this page.

Comment: you can change whatever you want in the Ionic framework if you modify enough of the components and css. Basically for this instance, you have to write your own css that will overwrite that of the ionic tabs css. give an ID to your ion-tabs so you can select .tabbar and modify its css elements. Modify .tab-button and any other node that is preventing positioning and then place the tabs wherever with the css on the ID you chose.

Comment: Not helping! I already told you I tried changing the sass file. I need specific code that can help. Otherwise don't bother commenting!

Comment: No need to be rude Jack. If you put a little effort into it, the above directions are actually exactly what you need to do. Just use that little noggin of yours to get it done. i'll give you a hint...tabbar {top: 0; bottom: auto};

Comment: Your code didn't work I already tried it when I said I edited the Sass file. I Solved it with a little html code.